# Obtain Model Identifier string on macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-foundation

---

Every Mac has a model identifier, for example "Macmini5,1". (These are shown in the System Information app.)

[image]

How can I programatically obtain this model identifier string?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that string? There might be a better alternative.

Comment: @uchuugaka: My app has a "Send Feedback" button. When the user clicks it, a mail compose window appears, pre-filled with their software version and OS version. I want to add the hardware info to that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sysctl`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <sys/sysctl.h>

NSString *ModelIdentifier()
{
    NSString *result=@"Unknown Mac";
    size_t len=0;
    sysctlbyname("hw.model", NULL, &len, NULL, 0);
    if (len) {
        NSMutableData *data=[NSMutableData dataWithLength:len];
        sysctlbyname("hw.model", [data mutableBytes], &len, NULL, 0);
        result=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Code still working well for me 8 years later. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

**Swift 4+ using IOKit**

```
import IOKit

func getModelIdentifier() -> String? {
    let service = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault,
                                              IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"))
    var modelIdentifier: String?
    if let modelData = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(service, "model" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeRetainedValue() as? Data {
        modelIdentifier = String(data: modelData, encoding: .utf8)?.trimmingCharacters(in: .controlCharacters)
    }

    IOObjectRelease(service)
    return modelIdentifier
}
```

Comment: Requires IOKit to be added to the frameworks through your target's "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content". If its a Catalyst App, strongly recommend wrapping the import and associated func in an #if targetEnvironments(macCatalyst).

Comment: I've never had to add IOKit to my target's frameworks. Perhaps it is only necessary to do this for a Catalyst app?

Comment: Yeah, this is exclusively for getting Mac related information which UIDevice or DeviceKit cannot (yet) capture.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `IOKit.framework`. I think it's best choice.

This simple code example shows how to read model identifier from I/O Kit registry to `NSString`:

```
- (NSString *)modelIdentifier {
    io_service_t service = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, 
                                                       IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"));

    CFStringRef model = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(service, 
                                                        CFSTR("model"), 
                                                        kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                        0);

    NSString *modelIdentifier = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(__bridge NSData *)model 
                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    CFRelease(model);
    IOObjectRelease(service);

    return modelIdentifier;
}
```

---

Strings **"IOPlatformExpertDevice"** and **"model"** in code above is used to read model identifier from I/O Kit registry. `ioreg` command line tool is your friend, when you want to find information from I/O Kit registry. This image shows those strings in `ioreg` output:

[image]

I hope this helps to use `IOKit.framework`.

Comment: You are casting from `CFStringRef` to `NSData` which is obviously an error

Answer (score 6):

[Answer from Ryan H](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50008492/1107913) is correct except improper conversion from `null-terminated string` to `Swift String`, giving result with `\0` symbol in the end, which you may not expect, performing full match. This is corrected version:

```
static private func modelIdentifier() -> String? {
    let service = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"))
    defer { IOObjectRelease(service) }

    if let modelData = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(service, "model" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeRetainedValue() as? Data {
        return modelData.withUnsafeBytes { (cString: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> String in
            return String(cString: cString)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: `let cString = model.withUnsafeBytes({ $0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) })` for Swift 5.

Comment: Just a quick FYI that my answer was updated a while back to remove the null-terminator (in a way that doesn't require reading the bytes).

Answer (score 3):

You can get the same output from the [system_profiler](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/system_profiler.8.html) command. It has an `-xml` option that you can use. `NSTask` can run the command for you and you can parse the result.

---

**Sample code:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSString *ModelIdentifier() {
    NSPipe *pipe=[NSPipe pipe]; 
    NSTask *task=[[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/sbin/system_profiler"];
    [task setArguments:@[@"-xml", @"SPHardwareDataType"]];
    [task setStandardOutput:pipe];
    [task launch];

    NSData *outData=[[pipe fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile];
    NSString *outString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:outData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return [outString propertyList][0][@"_items"][0][@"machine_model"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 16 apps that also build to Mac Catalyst any solution here that uses `kIOMasterPortDefault` (such as Ryan H's) will generate a build error:

> 'kIOMasterPortDefault' is unavailable in Mac Catalyst

Attempting to switch `kIOMasterPortDefault` to `kIOMainPortDefault` may also give a build error depending on which versions of Catalyst you are targetting – and I found trying to use `#available` to get around that didn't work either.

If you run into that situation then try the following, which is a reformulation of Parag Bafna's answer into Swift:

```
var modelIdentifier: String {
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    var size = 0
    sysctlbyname("hw.model", nil, &size, nil, 0)
    
    var modelIdentifier: [CChar] = Array(repeating: 0, count: size)
    sysctlbyname("hw.model", &modelIdentifier, &size, nil, 0)
    
    return String(cString: modelIdentifier)

    #else
    // Handle iOS
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift version of [Parag Bafna excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20072869/775083)

```
var deviceName: String {
        var str = "Unknown Device"
        var len = 0
        sysctlbyname("hw.model", nil, &len, nil, 0)
        if len > 0 {
            var data = Data(count: len)
            sysctlbyname("hw.model", &data, &len, nil, 0)
            if let s = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                str = s
            }
        }
        return str
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CFStringRef model = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(service, 
                                                        CFSTR("model"), 
                                                        kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                        0);  ? type is ok ?
```

I think code maybe like this:

```
CFSDataRef model = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(service, 
                                                        CFSTR("model"), 
                                                        kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                        0);
```